# Decode hex string in java

Tags: java, hex, decode

As I'm trying to convert below hex to java string.
As this is UTF8 Characters.

`ЫЙБПАРО` As this string is converted into hexadecimal `42b41941141f41042041e` value.

I tried to convert string to hex by using below javascript code

```
function encode(string) {
     var str= "";
        var length = string.length;        
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){
            str+= string.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
            }
        return str;
}
```

I need to decode in java code what would be the way.

Tried below answers

[mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-java](http://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-java)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/140131](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131)

[Convert a string representation of a hex dump to a byte array using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java)

Comment: Anybody could ask more information before down voting the question.

Comment: We should not need to ask for more information. You should provide the code you have tried from the start. BTW I did not down vote your question.

Comment: Your question is *really* vague. It's not clear whether your input is actually the plain text or hex, or what encoding is being used, or what output you're expecting, or what you've already tried.

Comment: Refer link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086916/encode-decode-hex-to-utf-8-string

Comment: apart from all the above (@JonSkeet hiya there, Jon!) PLZCANIHAZTEHCODEZ questions aren't taken kindly here.

Comment: We shouldn't have to read a *different* question in order to understand *this* one. It's still not clear to me whether you're actually just trying to ask the same question again.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131 may be relevant though.

Comment: Could you please refer the question that i raised which was not answered. For that I'm trying to split my question in asking again.

Comment: Maybe this example helps you : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-hex-to-ascii-in-java/

Comment: @RahulP just because your previous question wasn't answered in a way satisfactory to you doesn't make this one a proper, understandable, unambiguous and spot-on question.

Comment: right but somebody could ask me to provide details instead of down vote it.

Comment: Your hex String is missing at least one digit. The number must be even.

Comment: How do you code the String to hexadecimal

Comment: esprittn : Added javascript snippet which converts string to hex which I'm sending through URL parameter

Comment: I find a solution: if you can change your JS function to generate a hex like this \u042B\u0419\u0411\u041F\u0410\u0420\u041E( hex code for ЫЙБПАРО) you can decode easily. I get this Hex code from this converter http://itpro.cz/juniconv/  I put it on System.out.println and I get ЫЙБПАРО and you must use UTF-8 on your project.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Apache Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/).

```
byte[] b= Hex.decodeHex(yourhexdecimalstring.toCharArray());
System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF8"));
```

Comment: have you ever tried above hexadecimal value by using your snippet.

Comment: Yeah, it returns me http://prntscr.com/5vm8dg

Comment: And it is incorrect right. :p
Actually in java side it always try to split hex in 2 digit and try to convert it to string where as javascript converted character like pie(i.e. character of my string) into 3 digits.

Comment: Answer edited.(Note I haven't tried that yet).

Comment: up voting your answer. But still not working :'(

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the first character: this is #1067 in the Unicode table.
This means 4 x 256 + 43. So the hex-representation of this is 04 and 2B (or vice versa depending on the byte order). Yours seems to be 42 b4. So I assume the encoding is not correct.

I'm not familiar with jscript but this code...

```
private void jscript() throws ScriptException {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
    engine.eval("function encode(string) {\n"
            + "     var str= \"\";\n"
            + "        var length = string.length;        \n"
            + "        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++){\n"
            + "            str+= string.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);\n"
            + "            }\n"
            + "        return str;\n"
            + "}"
            + ""
            + "print(encode(\"ЫЙБПАРО\"));");
}
```

...returns this

> 42b41941141f41042041e

as you wrote. But in my opinion this is not correct

Comment: It's correct, I checking using online tool.